# Can't install SQL server on my Amazon Linux system (AWS EC2)

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I recently trying out AWS EC2 and launched an instance. I have just installed php successfully via *sudo yum install php php-mysql*

But when I try *sudo yum install mysql-server*, it says

> $ sudo yum install mysql-server
>   Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
>   amzn2-core                                                                                       >| 2.4 kB  00:00:00
>   No package mysql-server available.
>   Error: Nothing to do

May I know how can I get it to install SQL server? Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: If you are on AWS, why not use Aurora? That's MySQL server that Amazon provides. But more to the point, it appears that Amazon Linux doesn't know what the package called "mysql-server" is. Try searching for "mysql" first to see if it's called something different on Amazon Linux package servers.

Comment: have you done sudo yum update?

Comment: Package names vary from distro to distro. Do a search.

Answer (score 3):

Run below resolved for me

```
rpm -ivh https://repo.mysql.com//mysql57-community-release-el7-11.noarch.rpm

rpm -ivh https://repo.mysql.com//mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm

yum install mysql-server
```

https://www.techietown.info/2017/07/error-no-package-mysql-server-available-while-installing-mysql-server/

Answer (score 2):

Check out this tutorial >> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html

I think the package name might be incorrect as the one in the tutorial is `mysql56-server`. You could also do a `yum search mysql` as suggested above to find the appropriate package.